# Retrieving Class Name from an Object in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to retrieve the class name of an object. When I tried using the const_get, i am getting the entire model's table structure. So I used the following code.

**Code**

```
  def classname(object)
    return object.class.to_s.split("(")[0]
  end

  def classrating(object_id)
    classtype = classname(object_id)
    return classtype
  end
```

**Script/Console**

```
  >> q = Question.new
    => #<Question id: nil, question_info: nil, profile_id: nil, rating: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
    >> Question.classname(q)
    => "Question"
    >> Question.classrating(Question.classname(q))
    => "String"
    >> q.class
    => Question(id: integer, question_info: string, profile_id: integer, rating: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

As you can see, when Question.classname is called, it returns Question and when the same input i called from Question.classrating, it returns String. I am just returning the same output from the Question.classname.

Can you please tell me whether what am I doing wrong, that the value gets changed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `classrating` is effectively the same as `classname`.  So you're basically doing:

```
classname(classname(Question.new))
```

You're returning the class name of the class name of `q`.  `q` is a `Question`, so the class name is `"Question"`.  `"Question"` is a `String`, so its class name is `"String"`.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, you can just use `object.class.name` to get an object's class name as a string.

The reason that your second call returns "String" is simply that you call `Question.classname(q)` which returns `"Question"` and then you call `Question.classrating("Question")` which returns "String" because `"Question"` is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Question.classname returns the string "Question". The type of that string is obviously string.
Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

Code is wrong. I must not have the classname method in the classrating method.Damn :D. Sorry